# Generate static HTML from full dynamically generated page, .NET Core 3.1

Tags: .net-core, static-html

I have a simple .NET Core 3.1 app that generates pages, as web apps usually do. The dynamic website looks great, but I need to save the output as full static HTML pages to be saved somewhere. Is there an easy way to do this within the web app code that takes the full page once fully generated or should I scrape the generated page with a separate program?

I am making use of Razor Pages with the MVVM design pattern.